# Elliptic Curve - Prime Generator

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithms

This question is in regards to the prime generator for an elliptic curve. I have taken the prime curve $\mathbb Z_p$ and have the $5$ prime number factors for the prime curve using Euler's Totient. Is there an algorithm to figure out prime generator(s) for the curve without using the naive approach for testing each integer which passes the congruency test for not being equal to $1 \mod p$?

Comment: What do you mean by “prime curve $\mathbb Z_p$”? I can’t understand what you’re asking for.

Comment: prime curve means curve over finite field which is prime for example F_13441. 13441 is the prime for this curve.

Comment: There is no curve around specified. The  **field** $\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ (prime) elements can be used as base field for a lot of curves. If $p\ne 2,3$ an equation of an elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_p$ can be taken (after eventually changing the curve by an isomorphism) to be of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, $a,b$ being constants in the field. So please edit the question to be well defined, and then provide content, e.g. show the own effort to solve the issue, for instance in some "small cases" like $p=5$ or $p=7$. (This will also make clear which is the question.)